# Add an HTML class to a DOM element controlled by two.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, two.js

I'm trying to add a class and ID to specific Two.js objects in this project: http://itpblog.evejweinberg.com/Homework/Open/ (click a few times to play)
If I console.log the word 'background' I see that these are two.js objects but I can't seem to use css or jquery to add a class/ID to them.

Any help is appreciated!

I even tried adding it to the whole project but that did not work:

```
$(document.body).addClass("dropshadow");
```

Comment: Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question if you want someone to answer it. And be more descriptive about the problem you're facing.

Comment: That project is rad! Nice work.

Comment: omg thx! @jonobr1 - means a lot coming from you!

Answer (score 2):

two.js entities are not DOM elements themselves, but each Scene, Group, or Polygon contains at least one reference to the DOM element that gets drawn when the entity is changed. To reference various DOM elements use the following syntaxes:

```
// Initialize two.js and attach to a dom element referenced by `canvas`
var two = new Two(params).appendTo(canvas);

// Two.Scene
var my_scene = two.renderer.domElement;

// Two.Group
var my_group = document.getElementById(two.scene.id);

// Two.Polygon — requires knowing the ID by means of your custom app logic.
var my_poly  = document.getElementById(my_poly_html_id);
my_poly.classList.add('my-class');
```

Here's a screenshot showing all three commands in an actual app along with the outcome of each, with one additional command add a class to the shape that was targeted. The syntax of the last command differs but I omitted the `var` statements so that the console would display the result instead of outputting `undefined`.

[image: screenshot of a two.js scene and console output of the previously listen commands]

If you'd like to create custom HTML IDs for individual shapes, use the `.id` setter before the initial render of your shape. Since most of this code is just setup, [I offer a practical example on one of my own projects](https://github.com/rupl/bustashape/blob/73ade31df7a5ad8e53e860010ae19dcc70a8bf25/js/client.js#L44-L62). In that snippet, a `shape` variable holds a new instance of `Two.Polygon` so calling `shape.id = 'something-unique'` before calling `two.update()` to draw the shape for the first time results in a DOM element with a custom HTML ID. **Here is an incomplete block of setup code** showing how to set the ID:

```
// Create new shape
var shape = two.makeRectangle(START_X, START_Y, START_WIDTH, START_HEIGHT);

// Set custom ID
shape.id = 'shape-' + Math.random(10000000);

// Draw shape for first time.
two.update();
```

Comment: In addition to what @Chris Ruppel is describing, once `two.update` has been called since the instantiation of a new shape. You can reference the element directly: e.g `shape._renderer.elem`. This is an `SVG` element and can be modified as such: `$(shape._renderer.elem).addClass('my-class');`. Happy coding!