# Can I add class to dynamically created two.js element?

Tags: javascript, two.js

I am using the code showed below to create 46 small circles within a wrapper (div) draw-shapes;

```
let elem = document.getElementById('draw-shapes');
let params = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
let two = new Two(params).appendTo(elem);

for (let i = 1; i < 47; i++) {
  circle = two.makeCircle(x, y, radius);
  circle.fill = 'green';
  circle.stroke = 'white';
  circle.linewidth = 1;
  circle.id = i;
}
```

All drawings are made with the Two.js library. I read in the documentation I can change the id of the created element, but I also need to assign a class to each element. I have tried everything from pure js setAttribute to jQuery .attr and .addClass methods, but none of them worked, so I started to wonder if this is even possible to do? If someone knows a way, please let me know how. Thank.

Comment: Post at least one of the attempts you made and someone can help you find out what went wrong.

Comment: Maybe the issue is related to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399675/add-an-html-class-to-a-dom-element-controlled-by-two-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an HTML class to a DOM element controlled by two.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399675/add-an-html-class-to-a-dom-element-controlled-by-two-js)

Comment: @AndrewL64 what you mean? It's Two.js so the html is just <div id="draw-shapes"></div> ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not internal utility or property to get to the DOM node of each Two element.

But the `id` you specify is indeed added as `two-<specified-id>` to the actual node.

So you can use the normal `document.getElementById`.

So in your case

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('draw-shapes');
let params = {
  width: 300,
  height: 300
};
let two = new Two(params).appendTo(elem);

for (let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  const circle = two.makeCircle(i * 10, i * 10, 40);
  circle.fill = 'green';
  circle.stroke = 'white';
  circle.linewidth = 1;
  circle.id = `two-circle-${i}`;
}
two.update();

// add classname to every fifth element;
for (let i = 1; i < 20; i += 5) {
  const circleNode = document.getElementById(`two-circle-${i}`);
  circleNode.classList.add('classname');

  circleNode.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    const path = two.scene.getById(this.id)
    path.scale = 1.2;
    two.update();
  });

  circleNode.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    const path = two.scene.getById(this.id)
    path.scale = 1;
    two.update();
  });
}
```

```css
.classname {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: red;
  fill:yellow;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/two.js/0.6.0/two.js"></script>

<div id="draw-shapes"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting error -> uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null when using your example.

Comment: @JakubMoz indeed. You need to call `update` before the nodes are in the DOM. Updated code with a working example.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick question. I wanted to add a class to these elements, because I wanted to add box-shadow or drop-shadow to them to create an effect of outer glow, but none box-shadow: or filer: drop-shadow(); works in the css.

Comment: @JakubMoz see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3 for applying drop shadow. (*you need to do it through svg, not CSS*)

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to do it via css with only adding drop-shadow to the svg element in css.

Comment: @JakubMoz cool. that will only work on chrome and firefox though, right ?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, IE 11, IE 10 and can't test on lower IE because I can't install it on Win10

Comment: I will just quickly ask here instead of posting another question. Is there a way to scale the circle on hover without breaking the position? Like on this picture https://i.imgur.com/ejhHL7M.png on hover circle I want it to be like 20% or 30% . I have tried transform:scale(1.3); but it breaks the position even with transform origin it doesn't work.

Comment: @JakubMoz use the [`.scale`](https://two.js.org/#path-scale) property of the Two.js paths. Updated answer with the functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I have the ability to scale specific path circle like some circles for ex 5,6,7 should have different scale on hover than others.

Comment: I ended up adding separate div behind the whole two scene and using jquery.hover() I detect position on hovered element and place the div at the same position stimulating hover effect. I think it's even better because I am not setup/redraw the whole scene each time I hover an element which will consume lots of cpu because I have like 500+ nodes and that much lines.